# Excel Filter with formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet, formulas

I have the following data:

```
Date        Day         Ranch
25/05/2018  Friday      FALSE
26/05/2018  Saturday    TRUE
27/05/2018  Sunday      FALSE
28/05/2018  Monday      FALSE
29/05/2018  Tuesday     TRUE
30/05/2018  Wednesday   FALSE
```

I would like to have a formula which scans the ranch column for the lowermost TRUE value, and remembers it's corresponding date, then scans the ranch column for the second-most-low TRUE value, and remember it's corresponding date, and then subtracts the first date from the second date.

To put it a bit more simply, I want to add a column to this table which tells me the days since the last TRUE value occurred. so the resulting table should look something like this:

```
Date        Day         Ranch    Days since last Ranch
25/05/2018  Friday      FALSE    0 (Hardcoded)
26/05/2018  Saturday    TRUE     0
27/05/2018  Sunday      FALSE    1
28/05/2018  Monday      FALSE    2
29/05/2018  Tuesday     TRUE     0
30/05/2018  Wednesday   FALSE    1
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming above mentioned data is in grid `A2:C7` you can try below formula:

`=IF(C2,0,IFERROR(A2-LOOKUP(2,1/$C$1:C1,$A$1:A1),"0/Unknown"))`

I have assumed that column C values are Boolean values.